# Roslocate shows wrong package version - how do I install the right one?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosseral-arduino, rosserial, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just installed ROS Kinetic from source on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Stretch), and I'd like to add rosserial and rosserial_arduino.  When I looked up the packages with roslocate, I got this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ roslocate info rosserial
Using ROS_DISTRO: kinetic
- git:
    local-name: rosserial
    uri: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
    version: jade-devel

pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ roslocate info rosserial_arduino
Using ROS_DISTRO: kinetic
- git:
    local-name: rosserial_arduino
    uri: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
    version: jade-devel
```

I haven't generated a rosinstall including these yet, because I'm worried about those version descriptions.  Is it nothing to worry about, or do I have to do something special to get the Kinetic versions rather than the Jade ones?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313218/roslocate-shows-wrong-package-version---how-do-i-install-the-right-one?/) by [TrevorMuraro](https://answers.ros.org/users/39376/trevormuraro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own question after looking at the details of older versions on rosserial's wiki page: it's actually the right version.  Rosserial jade-devel is the version to use for Kinetic (and Lunar.)

---

Originally posted by [TrevorMuraro](https://answers.ros.org/users/39376/trevormuraro/) with karma: 16 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0